# Meteor-Bootstrap jQuery wrong version

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I do have the following message in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires at least jQuery v1.9.1 but less than v3.0.0
```

In .meteor > version file it says it's `jquery@1.11.9`.

- I did tried to meteor remove and the install again both jquery and boostrap separately.
- Also tried to manualy change current version in .meteor version file to 1.9.1 first in terminal it says: 
  `jquery  upgraded from 1.9.1 to 1.11.9`
  But after server restart the current version is back to 1.11.9

What can be done to retrieve the favor of the javascript gods?

Comment: Which version of Meteor are you using, how are you installing Bootstrap (Atmosphere, NPM) and which Bootstrap package are you using?

Comment: @vanburen I am currently on Meteor 1.3.3.1, Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.2 (installed via meteor add)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may happen when you have other npm packages with jQuery dependency defined as `>= 1.9.1`

In that case, if no other package defines a more strict version, npm will automatically take the most recent version that complies with this dependency specification, i.e. jQuery 3+ in that case.

If you are in that situation, a simple workaround is to add a more strict [version specification](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) in your `package.json` file, e.g. `"jquery": ">=1.9.1 <3.0.0"`

Comment: Don't forget to run"npm install" after.

Answer (score 1):

A few google searches got me here: https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-and-bootstrap-doesnt-work-error-bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery/15597/8

What it says is:

1. Add the jquery package back in: `meteor add jquery`
2. Remove bootstrap everywhere you have it (all locations - so completely remove the bootstrap directory in your project root, remove it from the js directory in your project root, and remove it from your client/lib directory).
3. Remove jquery everywhere you have it (all locations - so remove it from your client/lib directory and your js directory).
4. Remove the references to Bootstrap and jQuery in your index.html - so completely remove:
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="client/lib/a_jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="client/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

What happens when you follow those steps?